# Attaching the `snow` package in `R` creates a `.Random.seed` in the `.GlobalEnv`

Tags: r, random, random-seed, snow

I noticed when creating a `PSOCK` cluster via `parallel` that the child processes were by default populated with a `.Random.seed.`. This confused me because there is nothing in the documentation to indicate that this should be the case. More specifically, section ***6 Random-number generation*** from the vignette of `parallel` says that the `.Random.seed` is created **when the random generation is first used** (i.e., see bold text below).

> When an `R` process is started up it takes the random-number seed from the object `.Random.seed` in a saved workspace or **constructs one from the clock time and process ID when random-number generation is first used** (see the help on `RNG`). Thus worker processes might get the same seed because a workspace containing `.Random.seed` was restored or the random number generator has been used before forking: otherwise these get a non-reproducible seed (but with very high probability a different seed for each worker).

This appears to be corroborated by the information under *Note* in `?RNG` (e.g., "one is created [...] when one is required"):

> Initially, there is no seed; a new one is created from the current time and the process ID when one is required. Hence different sessions will give different simulation results, by default. However, the seed might be restored from a previous session if a previously saved workspace is restored.

This sent me down a nasty rabbit hole of painstaking debugging only to learn that this `.Random.seed` is created by a package that I import that in turn depends on `snow`.

To reproduce this, consider the following code in a file called `script.R`:

```r
# Expect the global environment to be clean.
cat("Before package load:", paste0(ls(all.names = TRUE)), "\n")

# Load package.
library(snow)

# Expect the global environment to remain clean.
cat("After package load:", paste0(ls(all.names = TRUE)), "\n")
```

Running `Rscript script.R` yields:

```
Before package load:  
After package load: .Random.seed
```

I am afraid that this question might generate opinionated answers and be flagged as inappropriate. However, I really want to know whether this behavior is considered acceptable, i.e., for a package to populate the `.GlobalEnv` while it is being attached. And whether there are any unintended consequences to this.

---

**Additional information:**

For those curious what exactly in `snow` is invoking the `RNG`, it seems that the `RNG` is invoked inside the function [`initDefaultClusterOptions()`](https://github.com/cran/snow/blob/b83f63db1072533b85e6e3146c51b7fca007425c/R/snow.R#L127) for selecting a port number:

```r
11000 + 1000 * ((stats::runif(1L) + unclass(Sys.time())/300) %% 1)
```

And then `initDefaultClusterOptions()` is called from within [`.onLoad()`](https://github.com/cran/snow/blob/b83f63db1072533b85e6e3146c51b7fca007425c/R/snow.R#L615) when the package is being attached.